# Repair Citrix Clipboard functionality on Linux

Tags: clipboard, citrix

I can no longer copy and paste between Citrix icaclient applications and local applications as was.  The [Citrix support](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX104631) states

> This issue occurs when a third party application inserts itself in the Windows clipboard chain on the local computer or in a session.

I am running Arch Linux with the KDE desktop but I assume the same thing is happening with Klipper.

The support advises to run [RepairCBDChain](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX106226), but that solution is for a windows system.  I cannot find anything similar for Linux or OSX.  From what I understand, there are two solutions: somehow replicate the RepairCBDChain utility or identify the offending application to prevent the issue from reoccurring.  How can I do either of these?

Comment: What did you do that caused it to stop working?

Comment: @eyoung100 That's a mystery.  I don't remember any significant action that happened between it working and not working.

Comment: Well you copied something like an exe or a bin file from somwhere that has no equivalent paste in windows or vice versa, you copied something from kde into Windows that Windows doesn't like... Can you install a clipboard viewer in the Windows ICA?

Comment: @eyoung100 I was copying an excel cell from ICA Excel to a local Chromium.  I had done that before multiple times and it behaved just like it would on windows before.  Perhaps an update broke that? I can't install anything on the Windows ICA.  But I can copy from local to ICA and from ICA to ICA.

Comment: You need a clipboard history viewer like [Clipboard Manager](http://www.outertech.com/en/clipboard-manager) to remove the offending item from Windows then paste something different into KDE.  If that doesn't work, you need to restart klipper and all ICA's to erase the histories, and hopefully it will start working again.